# SQL Server converting integers to decimal

Tags: sql-server

I looked at this post: [How to convert integer to decimal in SQL Server query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271548/how-to-convert-integer-to-decimal-in-sql-server-query) but it is not doing as I had expected.

I have a simple equation - `( [X] - [Y] ) / [X]` where X and Y are arbitrary `int` values from columns. I would like to store the result as a decimal including 1 (or 100%). But when I try to query this, I don't seem to be getting what I expect. If I use the query below - I get 0.

Here is my query so far:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(3, 2), (s4.Duration - s2.Interruption_Min_Total) / s4.Duration) AS Percentage
```

If you need to see more of my actual query, please ask - I will post it if need be.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just multiply by *`1.0`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force SQL Server to convert `int` used in the division into a decimal first, then SQL Server will return a decimal:

```
DECLARE @v1 INT;
DECLARE @v2 INT;
DECLARE @v3 INT;

SET @v1 = 5;
SET @v2 = 2;
SET @v3 = 4;

SELECT (@v1 - @v2) / @v3;

SELECT (@v1 - @v2) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @v3);
```

Please take a look at the answers on [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale/77675#77675) question.

Comment: So it's not `mysql` deleting my answer

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thank you for the other link too. I will accept as soon as it lets me

Comment: Check your tags next time @HardTacos , glad your problem was solved

Comment: @xPeke Yeah,apologies for that - I edited it as soon as I saw your comment. Really appreciate your help though!. ps - #‎OrigenWIN